# Alfresco delete node permanently using a web service

Tags: alfresco

I am trying to delete a node in Alfresco(CE, v. 2.1) permanently(without moving it to trash can first) using web service.

My use case is this: create a standalone job that queries the repo for files older than 2 years and delete them permanently using web service. Then the cleanup job moves the deleted files to content.deleted which I can safely delete.

Below is my code

```
import org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.CML;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.CMLAddAspect;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.CMLDelete;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Node;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Predicate;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Reference;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Store;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.AuthenticationUtils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.Constants;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.ContentUtils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.WebServiceFactory;

public class NodeDeletionService {

    protected static final Store STORE = new Store(Constants.WORKSPACE_STORE,
            "SpacesStore");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            AuthenticationUtils.startSession("admin", "admin");

            RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub repositoryService = WebServiceFactory
                    .getRepositoryService();

            Reference reference = new Reference(STORE,
                    "8abb6223-11bb-11e4-a335-65e3a9c8626a", null);
            Predicate predicate = new Predicate(new Reference[] { reference },
                    null, null);
            Node[] nodes = repositoryService.get(predicate);

            CMLDelete delete = new CMLDelete(predicate);

            CML cml = new CML();

            cml.setDelete(new CMLDelete[] { delete });

            CMLAddAspect addAspect = new CMLAddAspect("temporary", null, predicate, null);

            cml.setAddAspect(new CMLAddAspect[]{addAspect});

            // Execute the CMLDelete statement

            try {
                WebServiceFactory.getRepositoryService().update(cml);
                System.out.println("Deleted succesfully");
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                System.err.println("Can not delete the space.");
                throw e2;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            AuthenticationUtils.endSession();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an exception

`{http://www.alfresco.org/ws/service/repository/1.0}RepositoryFault:<ns1:errorCode>0</ns1:errorCode><ns1:message>org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.InvalidAspectException: The aspect is invalid: {}temporary</ns1:message>
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}exceptionName:org.alfresco.repo.webservice.repository.RepositoryFault`

I tried different aspects like `temporary`, `cm:temporary`, `sys:temporary` - but all in vain. Any idea?

Comment: Is it possible to switch your code from the old WebServices code to using CMIS? Only CMIS is much better supported, so should be a lot easier to do...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am not sure whether my version 2.1 supports CMIS. In any case, after some struggle, got the problem resolved by changing aspect code to `CMLAddAspect addAspect = new CMLAddAspect(QName.createQName("http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0", "temporary").toString(), null, predicate, null);` 

Atleast this works!

Comment: Alfresco 2.1 was practically carved in stone tablets... No CMIS support at all there! Is there a reason why you're using such an old version?

Comment: we are using Alfresco more or less just as a file server. It was just ignored as it worked, until now when the repo. has balloned to over 500 gb.